# Weird results when running my program in gDebugger

Tags: c++, debugging, opengl, graphics

I'm trying to run a an OpenGL program through gDEBugger (http://www.gremedy.com) and I'm seeing a couple of strange things:

1. The frames seem to be rendering MUCH faster with gDEBugger. For example, if  I update some object's position every frame - it'll just fly across the screen really fast, but when the program is run without gDEBugger, it'll move at much slower speed.
2. Strangely, gDEBugger reports **8** GL frames/second. Which doesn't seem realistic: clearly, FPS is higher than 8 (btw I have checked every possible OpenGL Render Frame Terminator in the Debug Settings dialog). Here's a screenshot (click [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sBCmz.png) for full resolution):
   [image]

My program uses SDL to create an OpenGL rendering context:

```
Uint32 flags = SDL_HWSURFACE | SDL_DOUBLEBUF | SDL_OPENGL;
if(fullscreen) flags |= SDL_FULLSCREEN;

// Initialize SDL's video subsystem
SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_VIDEO) == -1;

// Attempt to set the video mode
SDL_GL_SetAttribute( SDL_GL_DOUBLEBUFFER, 1 );
SDL_Surface* s = SDL_SetVideoMode(width, height, 0, flags);
```

I'm using Windows 7 and an NVidia graphics card (geforce gtx 660m).

My question is, how does one explain the strange behavior that I'm seeing in 1) and 2) ? Could it be that for some reason the rendering is being performed in software instead of the graphics card?

UPD: Obviously, I'm calling `SDL_GL_SwapBuffers` (which isn't listed as one of render frame terminators) at the end of each frame, but I assume it should just call the windows SwapBuffers function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Regarding issue 1: apparently gDebugger disables wait-for-vsync, which is why the framerate is much higher than 60 fps.

Regarding issue 2: for some reason, when working with SDL, 2 OpenGL contexts are created. One can see the correct number by adding performance counters for the second context.

Comment: Two contexts are also listed when using GLFW. The second context is also the relevant one.